# Is there any way to break up a PDFTable onto a different page?

Tags: swift, pdf, tppdf

First time poster here...but been using StackOverflow for solutions whenever I get stuck.. ton of great information here! I will try to describe the question as thoroughly as I can and hope someone can help me out with it. I need to generate a PDF in Swift and present it on an iPad, so i decided to use TPPDF for the PDF generation and then Apple's PDFKit to present it.

TPPDF has been working great for me, however, I ran into an issue where if I create a PDFTable with an enough amount of rows, it overflows into the next page without creating a new table. The last row gets cut off about 1/3 way and the other 2/3 is generated on the next page. This creates a weird visual effect which i'd rather not have if it's possible.

I've been reading through the documentation as well as sifting through the source code to try and figure out if there's a way but I can't find a decent workaround. The only workaround I can think of is splitting up the content and creating multiple PDFTables on new pages (using the createNewPage() method). This would take a good amount of rework in my code so I wanted to post it here to see if anyone has come across this and come up with a solution.

I appreciate any help!!

-George

Answer (score 0):

thanks for asking, this is actually an on-going issue which occured after adding the merge-cell feature. This is discussed in issue [#243](https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF/issues/243), so you take a closer look at what's going on there.